# How to configure spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-security, cors

I have a problem with the config about spring-security. So I have made some configuration so far, and I am able to use all API with **GET. But none of the rest API like Delete-PUT-Post.
And for this I am getting an error like below:

The error is 403.[image]
[image]
[image]

So my configuration is in two classes :

> CorsFilter.java

```
package com.example.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.basic.auth;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class CorsFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
//        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS"))
//        {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
//        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {
    }
}
```

and the second class is :

> SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth

```
package com.example.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.basic.auth;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
        //http.cors();
        http .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
//            .formLogin().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

My controller is as below:

> ItemController

```
package com.example.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.todo;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class ItemController {
    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/users/{username}/items")
    public List<Item> getAllToDosList(@PathVariable String username){
        return itemService.findAll(username);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/users/{username}/item/{id}")
    public Item getItem(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable Integer id){
        return itemService.findById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/users/{username}/item/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Item> updateItem(@PathVariable String username,
            @PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Item item ){
        Item updateditem = itemService.saveItem(item);
                return new ResponseEntity<Item>(updateditem, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    @PostMapping("/users/{username}/item")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addItem(@PathVariable String username, @RequestBody Item item ){
        Item createdItem = itemService.saveItem(item);

                URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(createdItem.getId()).toUri();

                return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();             
    }
    @DeleteMapping(path = "/users/{username}/item/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> removeToDosFromList(@PathVariable String username,
            @PathVariable Integer id){
        Item todo = itemService.deleteToDoById(id);
                if (todo != null)
                {
                    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
                }

                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

And so far this work only for the GET API, Please have a  look in the classes, maybe you have more ideas than me, as I have a lack of experience.

Comment: Can you put the error you are getting? In the log I can only see debug traces, one of them says that DELETE /error doesn match with GET /** but there is no error per se.. Can you paste the controller where you are defining the DELETE /error route and the http status code you are getting in response?

Comment: Yeah, I will that now thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
```

You are passing OPTIONS method in the argument which is for specifying which method to allow, only OPTIONS type request will be allowed, use GET if you want to allow get requests. If you want to allow all request types just pass "/**" as the argument, with out specifying any method type.

Comment: I will try and let you know, I did this as when I call the get, I use a preflight request. So i just remove the option, and the get works as before but the other API do not work now i get **403**

Comment: But this is because all the other request (That are not OPTIONS) must be authenticated 

.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()

so you have to provide the authentication method you want to make the request work. If you don't do it, it is normal to get 403 - Forbidden

Comment: @JArgente what do you mean by that, I don't really understand you. 
Right now i have remove **OPTIONS** and i let only (**/**) and i get this error , shouldn't this work for all the API , I think now the problem is diff , have a look at the photos

Answer (score 0):

I think the question here is: 
do you want to autenticate the user to call some of the paths?

If the answer is no, you should remove this line `.anyRequest().authenticated()`

if the answer is yes you should specify the urls you want to be authenticated and define the authentication method and make the call with a proper Authorization header